# aws s3 Document versioning for pdf,docx files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I've eanbled versioning for the bucket created in s3
It's pefectly creating versions for images & videos

But Office documents it's not creating versions like .docx, .pdf files

Can idea how this works?
tried uploading files directly into bucket and checked.

Comment: What do you mean by it is not creating versions? Can you elaborate more? And you mean versioning is not working for docx and pdf files right?

Comment: Versioning applies to a whole bucket, so this seems not to be possible. Could you please Edit your question and provide more details of why you think that versioning is not working for some files? Were these files uploaded *after* versioning was enabled?

Comment: @RumeshEranga yes versioning is not happening for .docx files but for .pdf  it worked

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes versioning is applied to whole bucket; but no clue office documents unable to see versions

Answer (score 0):

Versioning in Amazon S3 applies to a whole bucket.

I did the following:

- Created a bucket
- Enabled versioning
- Uploaded a file
- Uploaded another file with the same name
- Clicked on the objected
- Clicked the **Latest version** link
- Both versions appeared

[image: Amazon S3 versioning]

What did *you* do?

**Update:** You asked for more uploads:

[image: Amazon S3 versioning]

Comment: Can you please try to upload the documents(.docx) for multiple times (for ex: 5 times) and how many versions are you able to see?

Comment: I can see *all* the versions (but I have to scroll to see them).

Comment: Two questions: Are you sure that Versioning is **enabled**? (It can be suspended.) Can you try uploading via the Amazon S3 console to see whether that correctly creates new versions? (Your app might be doing more than uploading.)

Comment: Yes you are right when i'm uploading from s3 console, it maintaining all the versioning as expected
Here goes my upload code which works fine with Images

http://imgur.com/a/x8tVk

Comment: That portion of the code doesn't seem to explain the behaviour.